# How the data annotation attribute validation is differ from client side validation in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

In the View Model, we are mentioning about  "`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`" and for the field names .. we are mentioning the validation such as ..

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter name")]
```

This is further called from `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`

My clarification is , When we can achieve the same from client side validation, what is the need for DataAnnotations (or) How would be the DataAnnotations differ or add more value on having it on the server side code?

Comment: Because the user may post unvalidated data to the server so there must be a mechanism to handle data validation at server-side and Data annotations provide information to the razor view to used validation for client-side as well as to server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we can achieve the same from client side validation, what is the
>   need for DataAnnotations.

Data annotation is not limited to server-side validation it provides a complete mechanism to maintain data integrity.

For instance, you are specifying this data annotation on your property.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter name")]
```

So it did three jobs for you regards to data validation.

1. In database schema, this property or field will be required
2. On the Client-Side, you cannot post a request without validated data.
3. On the Server-Side, you can check is data is validated or not.

So data annotations provide you a central way to handle all the data endpoints.

For instance, you are designing a web API that will be used by multiple clients. So the user may post any form of data so there must be a way to handle data validation, so data annotations help there.

Comment: Thank you  @habib, it is very helpful for me to understand the need for data annotation .. web api explanation is meaningful.. thanks